# I am passing a argument in express next(argument) so that express middleware function will catch it but why is it also going through app.all("*")))

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.use(Router)
```

//in route handler here i am passing the **next(err)**,why the app.all middleware is running, shoudn't the control go directly into express errror handling middleware skipping app.all//

````
app.all("*",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("app middleware ran")
    next(err)
})
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
  
res.status(400).send(err)
})```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR;

Use `throw err` instead of passing it to `next`. Using throw will redirect the request to the general express error handling middleware.

```js
app.all("*",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("app middleware ran")
    throw new Error('my error')
})
```

#### A little bit more

The `next` callback isn't used for passing errors/data to other middleware/routes. The `next` is used to continue the flow in the case that the middleware did its thing successfully.

A generic example is the good old `auth` middleware (usually using JWT)

```js
// pseudocode

// auth middelwhere
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    const jwt = JWT.decode(req.headers['Authorization'])
    if(jwt) {
       req.data.user = jwt; // append additional data to req context next middleware/routr
       next();              // user is authenticated go to next middleware/routr
    }
    else {
        // (1) use throw to pass error to "generic error handler"
        throw new Error('unable_to_authenticate');
        // (2) or handle error in the middleware
        res.status(401);
        res.end(); // Note: Don't call next() when resolving the request in the middleware
    }
})

// generic error handler
app.use((err,req,res,next) => {
  if(err.message === "unable_to_authenticate"){ 
     res.status(401);
     res.end(); 
  } 
  else if(...) { ... }
  else {
     res.status(500);
     res.end(); 
  }
})
```

Comment: It seems that if `next` is invoked with a non-null argument, control will pass to the general Express error handling middleware instead of the next middleware in the chain. I couldn't find this in the documentation though.